# Order Filtering on the Front End

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, orders, filter

I have a client that needs to be able to filter orders they placed.  Is there a way to do it when they try to use "View All" when viewing "My Account"?

Comment: What filters are you trying to apply? Date? Order Status? Payment method? Be specific.

Comment: Date, Order Status, Ship To.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out of the box.
In an unmodified Magento instance the orders in the customer history are selected as follows:

```
/* See Mage_Sales_Block_Order_History::__construct() */
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
```

In addition, the pager block applies the paging (in `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager::setCollection()`):

```
$collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());
$collection->setPageSize($this->getLimit());
```

If you want to add additional filtering capabilities you need to create an extension which provides the user interface for that and then applies those settings to the collection before it's loaded (which happens when `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_History::_prepareLayout()` is called.